# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException for string onStart()

Tags: android, android-fragments, activity-lifecycle

#### Problem

I've seen this question posted before, but the answers did not solve my problem, so I'm guessing it may be a different problem.

My code works well when I run it, but if I leave the activity on for a while and come back to it later - it crashes.

The activity contains a fragment, which itself contains a fragment. The crash occurs inside onViewCreated() on `getContext().getString(R.string.vote_for)`

#### Code

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    TextView description = rootView.findViewById(R.id.votes_chart_desc);
    description.setText(getArguments().getString("voteItemDesc"));

    int votesForNum = getArguments().getInt("voteFor");
    int voteAgainstNum = getArguments().getInt("voteAgainst");
    int voteAbstainNum = getArguments().getInt("voteAbstain");

    PieChart chart = rootView.findViewById(R.id.votes_chart);
    ArrayList<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    # CRASH happens here, inside the if, when evaluating getString().
    if (votesForNum > 0) entries.add(new PieEntry(votesForNum, getContext().getString(R.string.vote_for)));
    if (voteAgainstNum > 0) entries.add(new PieEntry(voteAgainstNum, getContext().getString(R.string.vote_against)));
    if (voteAbstainNum > 0) entries.add(new PieEntry(voteAbstainNum, getContext().getString(R.string.vote_abstain)));

    PieDataSet set = new PieDataSet(entries, "");
    set.setColors(ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS);
    PieData data = new PieData(set);
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.invalidate();
}
```

#### Stacktrace

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: [myprocess], PID: 11262
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0e003b
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2729)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1505)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0e003b
      at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:352)
      at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:398)
      at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:476)
      at [myprocess].Votes.VoteFragment.onViewCreated(VoteFragment.java:65)
      ...
```

#### Things I've tried / questions I've searched

1. [This question seemed similar (resource exists, but error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161435) - Cleaning the project did not help
2. [This is not similar, but similar exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177003) - `getString()` receives and ID as it should, and the program works until I change to a different app.
3. [Not similar to my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269502), OP had their layout removed somehow. My layout exists, and works until you switch apps.
4. [Duplicate of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658590), irrelevant.
5. [Duplicate of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468482), irrelevant.
6. Changing the crashing line to `rootView.getResources().getString(R.string.vote_for)`
7. Changing the crashing line to `getString(R.string.vote_for)`
8. Changing the crashing line to `getParentFragment().getActivity().getString(R.string.vote_for)`

#### Debugger info

I put a breakpoint on the problematic line, but the debugger disconnects after I switch between 9 apps, so I cannot come back to the crashing line after switching between apps. If my understanding of the activity lifecycle is correct, the crash happens only `onStop()`, `onResume()` resumes as normal.

I've tried resolving this issue on my own, but I failed. I'm out of ideas. Has anyone else encountered something similar? Thank you.

Comment: 1st clean project that is not work than try that getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.vote_for) or getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.vote_for)

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: It's not able to find one of the strings (`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException`). Make sure all those strings exists, clean your project and then retry.

Comment: Read my post, I did all of those things. The app works until I reload it.

Comment: Its clearly an issue of missing resource. What's there in strings.xml at `vote_******` strings..?

Comment: Check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338785/how-to-link-a-string-property-from-string-xml-in-android-fragment

Comment: @AnCoder Wow, this comment really helped. I have two strings.xml files, one in English, the other in Hebrew. The string was missing from the english xml file. I added the string to the english strings file, but now the string is in English even if the entire activity's locale is set to iw/he.

Comment: Make sure those strings are present in all string resource files (strings.xml).

Answer (score 0):

The problem stemmed from the fact that I had several string.xml files, and for some reason the locale changed after the `onRestart()` function. So as a result, `onViewCreated()` was referencing a different xml file than I was expecting. The solution was to just change locale in the `onResume()` function of the parent activity.

It's also good practice to keep the strings.xml files synced and not miss any values. Had I seen the strings in English, I would have been able to identify the problem much quicker.